# How many times larger should the gate resistors be than the drain resistor?

Tags: mosfet, resistors, gate-driving, open-drain

I was asked this question in class and could not come to a concise answer. This is question was asked in terms of MOSFET design. Are there any general rules or guidelines to follow?

Comment: Mosfets doesnt need gate resistors.

Comment: I will definitely take note of that

Comment: Even the drain resistor isn't a given, depending on the topology. A common-drain buffer should not have a drain resistor, and an integrated amplifier may use an active load instead of a drain resistor due to better performance and manufacturing limitations.